# Radio buttons acts as Check-box in TinyMce 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y62XB/), the type is `radio` but acts like `check-box`

```
{type: 'radio', name: 'letter', label: 'Letter'},
{type: 'radio', name: 'custom', label: 'Custom'},
```

I tried using them under one *name* that didn't work out, and my **2nd question:** how to make one of them as default(as selected).

Keep Smiling :)

Comment: You need to create buttongroup. Those act like checkbox because are not grouped.

Comment: using the same name for both buttons didn't work.

Comment: `type: 'buttongroup'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `tinymce/ui/Radio` class is not implemented yet. It act like a `tinymce/ui/Checkbox`.

You can use the `tinymce/ui/ListBox` class as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

for the 2nd question: `{type: 'radio', name: 'a', label: 'Letter', checked:'checked'}`

Comment: `checked:'I can type anything here it gets selected'`, but need something in exact according to tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

**Radio - not implemented yet**

See message here: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/ca0f454b9001b9f20aa26349b25f6d839c1a1146/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/Radio.less

and almost empty class `Radio.js`

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/0ab3af181284a060683b566d50e81381cc6445a9/js/tinymce/classes/ui/Radio.js