# Drop-down menu/ComboBox/listbox in TinyMce 4?

Tags: drop-down-menu, listbox, tinymce, tinymce-4

After doing some research in google for pretty long time found [some info](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:namespace.tinymce.ui) on `Drop down menu`, but the documentation doesn't have clear information for me to understand, or other docs are mostly on `TinyMce3`.  I've customized `TinyMce 4` adding a `button, menu and sub-menus` and have used `Window Manager` with `text box` and `radio button`(which is a `checkbox`, poor efforts I know), but I need a `drop down list/listbox` in `Window Manager`

**edit :** Radio buttons are [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607598/radio-buttons-acts-as-check-box-in-tinymce-4) in tinymce4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602764/how-to-add-tinymce-listbox-values-in-windowmanager)
helped a lot, I created a [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/LIdaab) so that might help somebody out there customizing [tinymce 4](http://tinymce.com)

Comment: plus 1 for the fiddle!