# tinyMCE setting not found (2 parts)

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

**Question 1:** I am wokring with tiny MCE 4 and have this bit of code

```
 editor.addMenuItem("item1", {
    text: "Name",      
    onclick: function() {
        editor.insertContent("<span id='Name' contenteditable='false'>[Name]</span>&nbsp;");
    },
 });
```

As you can see I am passing in a setting object where the fields `text` and `onclick` is set. Also if you look at the [example here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.addMenuItem) it uses a setting object with the field `text`, `context`, and `onclick`. But when I look at the [documentation for settings attribute](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.MenuItem) I do not see `context`, or `onclick` listed there. I looks at the `menu` and `button` also and could see anything there. Is there a more complete documentation somewhere?

**Question 2:** The reason I am asking this is because I want to see if there is a settings somewhere, that I can use to change the menus, for example, [in the fiddle mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493182/drop-down-menu-combobox-listbox-in-tinymce-4) instead of additional data displaying `list box`, I want the menu item used to display `list box` to be replaces with a textbox/dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example that you mentioned it is already explained that the context is where to you put your new menu item in the existing menu (Example configuration of a menu [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:menu)). So if you have an context "tools", you can add you new menu item to "tools".

```
editor.addMenuItem("item1", {
    text: "YourItemName",
    context: "tools",
    onclick: function() {
//The function of your menu item insert some content at the cursor position, is that corrent?
        editor.insertContent("<span id='Name' contenteditable='false'>[Name]</span>&nbsp;");
    },
 });
```

For your first question: No, at the moment the documentation of tinyMCE 4.x is still not complete. To learn more about how plugins (menus and buttons incl.) work, I downloaded the complete source code. I looked at some plugins (e.g. link plugin) and tried to understand the code there. At the moment the fastest way to learn some not-well-documented stuff.

For your second question: If you want to edit existing menus (or plugins), you have to download the dev-code and look the sources.